# How to persist Jpa entity with two @manytomany properties

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have an entity with two @manytomany anotated properties. The problem here is that, one of the properties is persisted while the other is not. What could be the problem. The entity is as follows.

```
@Entity("payment")
 public class PaymentData implements Serializable
{
    private Long pk;

    private Collection<PaymentItemData> paymentItem;
    /**
     *  minorPaymentItem
     *
     */
    private Collection<MinorPayItemData> minorPaymentItem;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "payitem_m_assig",
    joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "pay_item_id", nullable = false),
    inverseJoinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "minor_pay_item_id", nullable = false))
    public Collection<MinorPayItemData> getMinorPaymentItem()
    {
        return minorPaymentItem;
    }

    /**
     * @param minorPaymentItem the minorPaymentItem to set
     */
    public void setMinorPaymentItem(final Collection<MinorPayItemData> value)
    {
        this.minorPaymentItem = value;
    }



 @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "payitem_assigned",
    joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "pay_item_id", nullable = false),
    inverseJoinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "new_pay_item_id", nullable = false))
    public Collection<PaymentItemData> getPaymentItem()
    {
        return paymentItem;
    }

    /**
     * Set the property paymentItem
     *
     * @param value -paymentItem
     *
     */
    public void setPaymentItem(final Collection<PaymentItemData> value)
    {
        this.paymentItem = value;
    }    

}

 @Entity("minor")
    public class MinorPayItemData implements Serializable
    {

    }

 @Entity("major")
    public class PaymentItemData extends MinorPayItemData
    {

    }
```

The MinorPayItemData and PaymentItemData are saved in the same database. They are separated by a dicriminator column.

Only the paymentItem property is persisted. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: You did not specify cascade type. Try specifiying @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL);

Comment: What is the role of Cascade type to persisting the field.

Comment: persisting field to the database along with the entity you are persisting.

Comment: i have tried this but it doesn't work.